# Layout responsivo con css

Tags: css, html5, responsive, css-grid-layout

Buen dia!

Estoy aprendiendo css y quiero hacer el layout de un dashboard que contenga un sidebar, un nav en la parte de arriba y el contenido en el centro.

Lo estoy haciendo utilizando grid, pero no estoy seguro de si esta es la mejor manera de hacerlo, ya que quiero que en dispositivos moviles el sidebar siempre este oculto y se muestre al pulsar un boton un "hambuger button".

Oculto el sidebar reconstruyendo mi grid-templates-areas. Pero me gustaria que en dispositivos moviles ocupara toda la pantalla y apareciera con una sencilla animacion al presionar el "hamburger button", es por eso que no estoy seguro de que usar grid para hacer esto sea la mejor opcion

el codigo que tengo hasta ahora es el siguiente:

https://codepen.io/JohnatanDeLeon/pen/jOqVKjZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar flexbox en lugar de grid, es hay mas posibilidades con flexbox:

Por el alto en móbil no te preocupes ya que el contenido se encargará de ello.
Yo lo haría de la siguiente forma, solo restaría crear la funcionalidad del botón para que muestre nuevamente el contenidor que se oculta.

Puede probar esto, visualizalo en pantalla completa para que veas como queda.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}

.nav{
    background: #f00;
}

.nav li, .aside li {list-style-type: none;}

.contentDiv {
    width: 75%;
    order: 1;
}
.aside{
    width: 25%;
    background: #0f0;
}

.content{
    background: #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .content-wrapper {display: block;}
    .contentDiv, .aside {
          width: 100%;
    }
    .aside {display: none}
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">

    <div class="contentDiv">
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="">item1</a>
                    <a href="">item2</a>
                    <a href="">item3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <main class="content">

        </main>
    </div>
    <aside class="aside">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">item1</a>
                <a href="">item2</a>
                <a href="">item3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>     
    </aside>
    
</div>
```